# Get record from today date to next 10 days in yii

Tags: yii

Im working in yii framework. I want to get records which is going to expire within 10 days. Want to get records from today to next 10 days expired records.

I dont know how to achieve this in yii.

So far i have tried

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$now = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
$criteria->addCondition('expiry_date > "'.$now.'" ');
$domains = Domains::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But its not working....its returning me count of 0 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :

**Option : 1**

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'expiry_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)';
$domains = Domains::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

**Option : 2**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM domains WHERE expiry_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)";
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

I hope it will help.